# "No junit.jar" exception while running tests in IDEA 2021.3.3 Community Edition

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

I m trying to run Kotlin project's tests in IDEA 2021.3.3 Community Edition (debian Linux), please take a look at video https://ibb.co/cb8jhfW
I got the error "No junit.jar" and the following stack trace in the console:

```
com.intellij.execution.junit.JUnitUtil$NoJUnitException: No junit.jar
        at com.intellij.execution.junit.JUnitUtil.checkTestCase(JUnitUtil.java:393)
        at com.intellij.execution.junit.TestPackage.createJavaParameters(TestPackage.java:230)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:865)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:61)
        at com.intellij.execution.configurations.JavaCommandLineState.getJavaParameters(JavaCommandLineState.java:44)
        at com.intellij.execution.impl.DefaultJavaProgramRunner.patchJavaCommandLineParams(DefaultJavaProgramRunner.java:137)
        at com.intellij.execution.impl.DefaultJavaProgramRunner.lambda$doExecuteAsync$5(DefaultJavaProgramRunner.java:163)
        at com.intellij.execution.target.TargetEnvironmentAwareRunProfileState$1.run(TargetEnvironmentAwareRunProfileState.java:58)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:436)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:120)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:496)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:244)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:188)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:624)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:646)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:623)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:175)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:244)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1764)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

In the same time some tests from the sub-module of same project runs well (module integration_test for example) , could you tell what is going on?

**UPD** I have recorded the video of my problem, please take a look https://ibb.co/LS95PCN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that parent module has no tests itself, and no attached junit as well. You can change your run configuration to search 'in whole project' (acc to video, you have 'In single module'), then IDEA should find all tests.

[image: change to whole project]

Comment: it has no test itself but some of its submodules has: untegration_tests , regulation/regulation-core , validation/validation-core . It was possible to run them all from the root module in past, but something broke up

Comment: Use 'in whole project' to run tests from submodules when running parent.
Also, you previously could have 'all in directory' option. Now it's 'all in package' in your video. See reference dock here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-junit.html#configTab , hope this helps

Comment: Please tell me the difference between "all in package" and "all in directory." For now I can't even determine the number of tests in whole project

Comment: Actually I need to run all tests in project and when I run them one module by one I found 290 test. And when I run them through configuration "Whole project" ("all in package") I have found 293 test. What is that 3 test, I do not know :( How to ensure that ALL project's test have ran??